# ES6 make a class ready for user created Plugins

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I try to make a library in es6 with classes for slider etc. And i have a class like

```js
class MySlider {
  
  constructor() {
    // code
  }
  
  init() {
    // code
  }
  
  next() {
    // code
  }
  
  prev() {
    // code
  }
  
  regPlugin(name, plugin) {
    this.plugins[name] = plugin;
  }
  
 
}
```

And now i want that user can write Plugins to extend my Slider for example with slider thumbnails instead of dots. Like

```js
class SliderDots {
  
  constructor() {
    // code
  }
  
  reg() {
    MySlider.regPlugin("sliderDots", this)
  }
}
```

```js
import slider from './slider.js';
import sliderDots from './sliderDots.js';
import sliderNavigation from './sliderNavigation.js';
import sliderEpicFantasticPLugin from './sliderEpicFantasticPLugin';

var slider = new slider({ 'dots': true });
```

So you load mySlider.js and all the plugins you need. The idea is that you load the simple core and if you want to extend it you load only the modules you need. The only way i know is to extend a class is with "extends" but with this tactic it would'nt be work. Is this possible? Is it to complicated to explain it would be helpful how i can search for solution :) .

Comment: Why would it not work with this example? Why can you not do `class NewClass extends MySlider`?

Comment: Because you must instantiate the new class, or not `var slider = new sliderDots();` ? And how should it work if you load more than one Plugin? For the user it would be the best if you only speak with the core, i think. So you can load more or less plugins without changing code.